# Proposicion 4.2. of the book "An introduction to pseudo differential operators by Wong

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, differential-operators

[image]

Hi! Why $$(2\pi)^{-n/2} \int e^{-ix\xi}(D^{\alpha}\varphi)(x)dx=(2\pi)^{-n/2}\int \xi^{\alpha}e^{-ix\xi}\varphi(x)dx?$$

I tried using part integration with $u=e^{-ix\xi}$ and $D^{\alpha}\varphi(x)=dv$ but it did not work

Answer (score 1):

Integrate by parts $\alpha$ times. For example, the first one integrates $(D^\alpha \varphi)dx$ to $D^{\alpha-1} \varphi$ and differentiates $e^{-ix \xi}$ to $-\xi e^{-x\xi}$ thus getting
$$
\int e^{-ix \xi} (D^\alpha \varphi)dx 
  = e^{-x\xi} \left(D^{\alpha-1} \varphi\right)
    + \int \xi e^{-x\xi}\left(D^{\alpha-1} \varphi\right)dx
$$
and doing this $\alpha$ times reduces the differential by one and increments the power of $\xi$ by one as well, so you end up with 
$$\int \xi^\alpha e^{-x\xi} \varphi dx$$
as expected.

It remains to show the non-integral term is zero but that is likely a consequence of integration over $\mathbb{R}^n$...

Comment: thanks. The non-integral term that I have left is: $e^{-ix\xi}D^{\alpha-1}\varphi(x)+\xi e^{-ix\xi}D^{\alpha-2}\varphi(x)+ \xi^2e^{-ix\xi}D^{\alpha-3}\varphi(x)+\cdots+ \xi^{\alpha-1}e^{-ix\xi}D^{0}\varphi(x)$ but I do not know why it should be $0$

Comment: @eraldcoil could it be because you are integrating over $\mathbb{R}^n$? What assumptions are you making on $\varphi \in S$? Not sure about what else to suggest

Comment: S is the Schwartz space